# Query within a query - updating table1 from count of table 2

Tags: mysql

I'm not a sql expert, but I'm in the process of making changes to a custom built forum, and need to update a new field in one table with a count from another table. I'm trying to do this without iterating through all 20,000 forum posts.

The structure of the tables is as follows:

```
POST_TABLE:
ID, Post, Comment_count ...

COMMENT_TABLE:
ID, Comment, PostID ...
```

where `PostID` is the ID of the post that the comment is attached to in the `POST_TABLE`.

I want to update the new field Comment_count with the number of comments where `PostID=ID` for every post (comments in post, basically)

I'm guessing a single query can handle this, but I have no idea how to construct it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
update post_table p 
set Comment_count = (
    select count(id) from COMMENT_TABLE 
    where post_id = p.id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE post_table
   SET comment_count =
        ( SELECT COUNT(1)
            FROM comment_table
           WHERE postid = post_table.id
        )
;
```